# PHP and nuSOAP - variabls and class

Tags: php, nusoap

I look more about nuSOAP and now I need to know somthing about this nuSOAP :)

how can I build own variables like token, username and password so all my customer lookup on an API key?

My next question is, how can I build nuSOAP up from a PHP class, when I use `$srv->register("Connect");` its only a single function :) I really want to use "class" like `$client->class->function($var1,$var2);`.